# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, github

I have one dot net MVC apllication.When i run it on pc locally then it works successfully.After that I uploaded it on github and then agained cloned its new copy in my local machine..But if I am going to run it(cloned copy) now then it is giving following Server error..

**Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.**

Answer (score 0):

Check your references on the cloned copy. Are the references there? Do they have the red X through them. If so, you're going to have to restore the missing references before your cloned project will compile.

Reinstall all packages for a project using the nuget package manager
**Update-Package -ProjectName MyProject -reinstall**